# python 3 How to store result in array every repetition in a loop in the same index

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, append

I am using python-3.x and I have two loops. The first one which is runs 3 times and the second one that generates solutions (the loop runs 2 times).

What I want to do is: Collect the best solution from the second loop and append it to an array or a list. The next run, which is the first loop, will run the second loop again and it will collect the best solution from the second loop and append it to the same array or a list. This way, I will have two solutions for each loop run with the total will of six solutions.

The problem is: I want to append the "best solution" to same index in the next run.

In my case, the array will be a size of 6 indexes, but I want it to be the size of 3, where each index will include two values (the best solution).

Run 1: result inside the array: `index 0` "The first best solution." `index 1` "The second best solution."

Run 2: result inside the array: `index 0` "The first best solution" & "The first best solution".

`index 1` "The second best solution" & "The second best solution."

If you take a look at the code, the result should be clear and you'll see what I am trying to do.

Any advice or help you could provide, would be much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import random
import numpy as np
import pylab      
from numpy import median
import os
import subprocess as sp

run = 3
best_solutions = [np.empty(0)]
del best_solutions[0]

for i in range (run):
    lower = 300
    upper  = 500
    number_of_solutions = 50
    generate_solutions = 2 
    ####sub list 
solution = []
for ii in range (generate_solutions):     
    list_of_solutions = np.random.uniform(lower, upper, number_of_solutions)
#### append to the sub_list
    solution.append(min(list_of_solutions))
    lower = lower - 30.4323434
    upper  = upper - 90.634555
#### append the sub_list to best_solutions

    best_solutions.append(solution)
```

to make it even more clear...

If the (i) = 0 if the (ii) = 0 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 0

If the (ii) = 1 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 1

If the (ii) = 2 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 2 and so on......

second run: if the (i) = 1 if the (ii) = 0 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 0

If the (ii) = 1 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 1

If the (ii) = 2 the min(solution) from this loop will be stored in best_solutions in the index 2 and so on......

I hope this clarifies what I want to do!
I tried to store them by index:

```
best_solutions[ii].append(solution[ii])
```

but it gives me an error: `IndexError: **list index out of range**`

This is how my result should be:

```
 best_solutions
  Final result                   solution
 array or list                  array or list

Index                     Index
       ++++++++                 ++++++++      
       +  1   +                 +  1   +
  0    +  1   +            0    +  2   +
       +  1   +                 +  3   +
       ++++++++                 ++++++++
       +  2   +                 +  1   +
  1    +  2   +            1    +  2   +
       +  2   +                 +  3   +
       ++++++++                 ++++++++
       +  3   +                 +  1   +
  2    +  3   +            2    +  2   +
       +  3   +                 +  3   +
       ++++++++                 ++++++++
```

Comment: Is there a problem with indentation?

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by "indentation"

Comment: @azeez... I've cut out the non-relevant code you provided and made script to what it should look like. The code is with some inline comments to help you understand certain better. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for according to your "how it should be working". I've used example arrays with floating values to be able to show you the positions within each row and the sorting of the values at the end of the script, which was otherwise impossible if I had used integers.

```
import numpy as np

# test data
solution       = np.array([[1.1, 2.3, 3.2], [2.1, 1.2, 3.3], [1.3, 3.1, 2.2]], dtype = float)
best_solutions = np.zeros((3,3), dtype = float)

print solution

print best_solutions

shape_solutions = solution.shape
shape_best_solutions = best_solutions.shape

run, depth = shape_solutions

low   = 1.2
upper = 1.4

positions_1 = 0
positions_2 = 0
positions_3 = 0

for i in range(1, run+1):
    print 'check row : %s' % i
    for j in range(1, depth+1):
        value = solution[i-1][j-1]
        print 'row/depth : %s-%s - Got value "%s".' % (i,j, value)

        if value in [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]:
            print 'This is value : %s' % value
            best_solutions[0][positions_1] = value
            positions_1 += 1

            # this code is just here to show low and upper sorting creteria for your lower = 300 and upper = 500
            if low < value < upper:
                print "I've got a value ""%s"" between two limits ""%s-%s""..yeah!" % (value, low, upper)

        elif value in [2.1, 2.2, 2.3]:
            print 'This is value : %s' % value
            best_solutions[1][positions_2] = value
            positions_2 += 1

        elif value in [3.1, 3.2, 3.3]:
            print 'This is value : %s' % value
            best_solutions[2][positions_3] = value
            positions_3 += 1

print best_solutions

best_row, best_depth = shape_best_solutions

#sort values in each row/run
for i in range(best_row):
    best_solutions[i].sort()

print best_solutions
```

From my side the stdout looks like below:

```
[[1.1 2.3 3.2]
 [2.1 1.2 3.3]
 [1.3 3.1 2.2]]

[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]

check row : 1
row/depth : 1-1 - Got value "1.1".
This is value : 1.1
row/depth : 1-2 - Got value "2.3".
This is value : 2.3
row/depth : 1-3 - Got value "3.2".
This is value : 3.2
check row : 2
row/depth : 2-1 - Got value "2.1".
This is value : 2.1
row/depth : 2-2 - Got value "1.2".
This is value : 1.2
row/depth : 2-3 - Got value "3.3".
This is value : 3.3
check row : 3
row/depth : 3-1 - Got value "1.3".
This is value : 1.3
I've got a value 1.3 between two limits 1.2-1.4..yeah!
row/depth : 3-2 - Got value "3.1".
This is value : 3.1
row/depth : 3-3 - Got value "2.2".
This is value : 2.2

[[1.1 1.2 1.3]
 [2.3 2.1 2.2]
 [3.2 3.3 3.1]]

[[1.1 1.2 1.3]
 [2.1 2.2 2.3]
 [3.1 3.2 3.3]]
```

You want this?

```
[[[1.1],
  [ 1.2],
  [ 1.3]],
 [[2.1],
  [2.2],
  [2.3]],
 [[3.1],
  [3.2],
  [3.3]]]
```

Flexibility:

```
import numpy as np

# test data
solution       = np.array([[1.1, 2.3, 3.2, 4.1], [2.1, 1.2, 3.3, 4.2], [1.3, 3.1, 2.2, 2.4]], dtype = float)
#solution       = np.array([[[1.1, 4.1], [2.3, 4.2], [3.2, 4.3]], [[2.1, 4.4], [1.2, 4.5], [3.3, 4.6]], [[1.3, 4.7],[3.1, 4.8], [2.2, 4.9]]], dtype = float)

sort_filters = ((1.0, 1.4), (2.0, 2.5), (3.0, 3.4), (4.0, 4.4))

#  all values might be within range of one filter set. Better to set column length to max.
column_width    = solution.size
solutions_shape = solution.shape

print 'solutions_shape             : %s' % str(solutions_shape)
print 'best solutions column_width : %s' % (column_width)

# Select bast solutions array based on solutions array shape.
array_type = 0

if  len(solutions_shape) == 3:   # selects if it has 3rd dimension.
    print 'got 3d array', solution

    rows, subrows, columns = solutions_shape
    array_type           = 3
    # the number of rows are based on filter size
    best_solutions       = np.zeros((len(sort_filters), subrows, columns), dtype = float)

else:
    print 'got 2d array\n', solution

    rows, columns    = solutions_shape
    array_type     = 2
    # the number of rows are based on number of filter sets.
    best_solutions = np.zeros((len(sort_filters), column_width), dtype = float)
    print best_solutions



shape_best_solutions = best_solutions.shape

# location for best_solutions where next value should be stored.
next_position = {}

if array_type == 2:

    for i in range(1, rows+1):
#        print 'check row : %s' % i

        for j in range(1, columns+1):
            value = solution[i-1][j-1]
#            print '\nrow/columns      : %s-%s - Got value "%s".' % (i,j, value)

            filter_number = 0

            for selection_keys in sort_filters:
                x, y = selection_keys
#                print ' filter_no....   : %s - values : (%s, %s)' % (filter_number, x, y)
                row_position = filter_number
#                print ' next_position   : %s\n' % (next_position)

                # create row entry for position storage based on sort_filter sets
                if next_position.has_key(row_position) != True:
                    next_position[row_position] = 0
#                    print ' entry no. added : %s' % row_position

                if x < value < y:
                    #print 'This is value : %s' % value

                    column_position = next_position[row_position]
#                    print ' best sol.col.no : %s.' % column_position

                    best_solutions[row_position][column_position]= value
                    next_position[row_position] = column_position + 1
#                    print best_solutions
                else:
                    # print "no fit"
                    pass
                filter_number += 1


print best_solutions, next_position

# removes excess columns with zeros
last_column_with_values = next_position.values()

last_column_with_values.sort()

remove_column_from = last_column_with_values.pop()

best_row, best_columns = shape_best_solutions

best_solutions = np.delete(best_solutions, np.s_[remove_column_from:best_columns], axis=1)

print best_solutions

#sort values in each row/run
for i in range(best_row):
    best_solutions[i].sort()

print best_solutions
```

It should print:

```
solutions_shape             : (3L, 4L)
best solutions column_width : 12
got 2d array
[[1.1 2.3 3.2 4.1]
 [2.1 1.2 3.3 4.2]
 [1.3 3.1 2.2 2.4]]
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
[[1.1 1.2 1.3 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [2.3 2.1 2.2 2.4 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [3.2 3.3 3.1 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [4.1 4.2 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]] {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 3, 3: 2}
[[1.1 1.2 1.3 0. ]
 [2.3 2.1 2.2 2.4]
 [3.2 3.3 3.1 0. ]
 [4.1 4.2 0.  0. ]]
[[0.  1.1 1.2 1.3]
 [2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4]
 [0.  3.1 3.2 3.3]
 [0.  0.  4.1 4.2]]
```

Comment: thank you for the effort and time but it is not what I am looking for

Comment: .. explain what is wrong then because if its just a x/y conversion... that would be something you handle with pandas.

Comment: sorry for missing explaining,   but the length of the list depends on the generate_solutions so which can be 1 or more than 100, all of them are variables values (run and generate_solutions ). for example, if I have 100 run and 10 generate_solutions
the result will be list or array of:
size 10 where each index will include 100 solution

Comment: I see... then what you should do is `run, depth, column = shape_solutions` instead of `run, depth = shape_solutions` then in your first for-loop you implement that 3d "column" dimension. The index "row" and subindex "subrow" are made flexible because I'm asking what dimensions/shape the array is. With the code I've provided you you can play because your code as posted... didn't do anything at all except for three times creating variables with attached values...

Comment: Once you think you got it based on my above comment post an self-answer or if you run into errors again post the updated "try" in your question by making an edit comment and code beneath it. Then I'll look at it again. I'm coding behind my PC all day and if I'd would code it for you I prevent your learning-curve progress ;-)

Comment: thank you ZF007 for your advice I am not expert in coding and I am doing my best to solve this problem by my self but no luck so far. I can pay someone to solve it in 5 mints, which it is not my style. I want to learn by asking others ideas and advises not solutions.I will try your hints, and I will post the solution here if I find it, thank you again :)

Comment: I've added flexibility for a 2d-array and made position where you can write code for converting 3d array to 2d.

Comment: many thanks for your time, Finally, I find the best way to solve my problem :)